# Java Reflection: create new instance of interface give java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I've an EAR project structure:

EAR

- TestDependency.jar

  - MyInterface.class;
- TestEJBModule.jar

  - ExternalObject.class (implements MyInterface);
- TestWar

  - SingletonBean
  - MyTestClass  (implements MyInterface);

In Singleton bean I need to instantiate ExternalObject class  dynamically using the class name, but i get

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bsssrl.testejbmodule.ExternalObject cannot be cast to com.bsssrl.MyInterface
```

The code is:

```
    Class localclass = Class.forName("com.bsssrl.test.testwar.MyTestClass");
    Object olocal = localclass.newInstance();
    MyInterface local = (MyInterface) olocal;
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Test local.getString()   : {0}",local.getString());
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Test local.getAlfa()     : {0}",local.getAlfa());


Class exclass = Class.forName("com.bsssrl.testejbmodule.ExternalObject");
Object oex = exclass.newInstance();
if(MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(exclass)){
   MyInterface extern = (MyInterface) oex;
   LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Test extern.getString()  : {0}",extern.getString());
   LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Test extern.getAlfa()    : {0}",extern.getAlfa());
}else{
       LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Class {0} not implement MyInterface",exclass);
}
```

The class is:

```
public class ExternalObject implements MyInterface{

public Alfa alfa;

@Override
public String getString() {
    return "from external object in EJB module";
}

@Override
public Alfa getAlfa() {
    return alfa;
}

@Override
public void setAlfa(Alfa a) {
    this.alfa = a;
}

}
```

The first piece of code works, but the second launch ClassCastException;
I suppose I have a problem with classloader.

How can I solve it?

PS : I use wildfly-9.0.2.Final

Comment: try to verify if ExternalObject implements MyInterface.

Comment: @RayLloy i changed the code in the question adding a check...the check fails even if ExternalObject implements MyInterface

Comment: I've done the same test as java application and your check works fine. Are you sure you build TestEJBModule.jar after modification ?

Answer (score 1):

If you get classcast exceptions between compatible classes, it always means they've been loaded by different class loaders (very likely, as one is in a WAR the other in EAR) or that there's multiple versions of the class available and the wrong (incompatible) one is being picked up. With JBoss/Wildfly the latter is especially easy to happen as it has a messed up classloading strategy.

To test for the former, try setting the classloader to the same one that loaded `MyInterface` explicitly:

```
Class.forName("com.bsssrl.testejbmodule.ExternalObject", true, MyInterface.class.getClassLoader())
```

Comment: Tryed, i get the same error:
`ClassLoader clInterfaccia = MyInterface.class.getClassLoader();
localclass = Class.forName(classname, true, clInterfaccia);
olocal = localclass.newInstance();
if(MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(localclass)) -> false`

Answer (score 0):

I got a ClassCastException on

```
IService iService=(IService) classS.newInstance();
```

with

```
urlClassLoader=URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL(urlStr)});
```

and then add cast the class loader as parameter of newInstance, and that solved the problem for me:

```
urlClassLoader=URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL(urlStr)},IService.class.getClassLoader());
```